# Field not found: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to post api using asp not core with clean  architechture template. Except for my get api of token none other API's are working getting an exception of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning. I have shared my sql log  and swagger error screen shots.
I am following the steps according to https://docs.rxweb.io/rx-web-core/tours-of-contoso-app/Beginner/authentication
[sql log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeNdy.png)

[sql log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeNdy.png)
[swagger ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puJmZ.png)

This is the Configure Service

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       

        services.AddConfigurationOptions(Configuration);

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddPerformance();
        services.AddSecurity(Configuration);
        services.AddSingletonService();
        services.AddScopedService();
        services.AddDbContextService();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerOptions();
        services.AddMvc(options=> {
            options.AddRxWebSanitizers();
            options.AddValidation();
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(
            oo =>
            {
                var resolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                if (resolver != null)
                {
                    var res = resolver as DefaultContractResolver;
                    res.NamingStrategy = null;
                }
                oo.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
        //.AddJsonOptions(options => {
        //    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
        //    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        //    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        //    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        //});

    }
```

And my get/post methods are below

```
  public AuthenticationController(ILoginUow loginUow, IApplicationTokenProvider tokenProvider, IPasswordHash passwordHash)
    {
        this.LoginUow = loginUow;
        ApplicationTokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AllowRequest(MaxRequestCountPerIp = 100)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var token = await ApplicationTokenProvider.GetTokenAsync(new vUser { UserId = 0, ApplicationTimeZoneName = string.Empty, LanguageCode = string.Empty });
        return Ok(token);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymousUser]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(AuthenticationModel authentication)
    {
        var user = await LoginUow.Repository<vUser>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.UserName == authentication.UserName && !t.LoginBlocked);
        if (user != null && PasswordHash.VerifySignature(authentication.Password, user.Password, user.Salt))
        {
            var token = await ApplicationTokenProvider.GetTokenAsync(user);
            return Ok(token);
        }
        else
            return BadRequest();
    }
```

Comment: Please, share the code

Comment: I have shared the code and a link too, even after following steps according to the link I am getting that error.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details about your question